# I slice inside a NAL unit of type 1

Tags: h.264

I recently came across an interesting H.264 bit-stream and wanted to understand if it is valid in terms of the spec.

Assume there is a bit-stream consisting only of NAL units of type 1 (coded slice of a non-IDR picture), but inside these units there are slices of type 7 (I slice). Looking at the specification this seems valid, but up to this point I lived with the belief that I should always try to expect at least one NAL unit of type 5 (coded slice of an IDR picture) to start decoding, while this shows that I should also examine non-IDR pictures for I slices. Is that correct? Is there any rationale of not using IDR pictures and putting I slices inside non-IDR pictues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completely normal. If one slice in an AU (frame) is an IDR, that ALL VCL slices in that AU MUST also be IDR. The I slice allows you to mix I/P/B slices in the same AU. This allows for features such as periodic intra refresh